# Adding a column to a table from the previous row in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

Given a row with a timestamp column and some value column (from a device) which are already in a table in Azure SQL database, I want to add a new column to the row from a most recent record which meets certain criteria  (most recent will be defined by the timestamp column). The criteria is whether the value falls into a range (between 95 and 5). I want to do this for every row.

Here is an input table:

```
ts (Timestamp)       value (integer)
------------------------------------
2019-09-22 00:00:00  90
2019-09-21 23:10:05  75
2019-09-21 23:09:00  85
2019-09-21 22:09:00  00
2019-09-21 14:09:00  70
```

Now I want to add a column to this table:

```
ts (Timestamp)       value prev_value
---------------------------------------
2019-09-22 00:00:00  90    75
2019-09-21 23:10:05  75    85
2019-09-21 23:09:00  85    70
2019-09-21 22:09:00  00    70
2019-09-21 14:09:00  70    NULL
```

I have been trying different SQL statements but haven't bee successful so far.

Comment: Do you want to add a column to the table and populate it or do you want to query the table and compute a value for an additional column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want something like [`lag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but with a condition.
The easy way to do that is to use a correlated subquery.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ts datetime2,
    [value] int
)

INSERT INTO @T (ts, [value]) VALUES
('2019-09-22T00:00:00', 90),
('2019-09-21T23:10:05', 75),
('2019-09-21T23:09:00', 85),
('2019-09-21T22:09:00', 00),
('2019-09-21T14:09:00', 70);
```

The query:

```
SELECT ts,
       value,
       (
           SELECT TOP 1 value
           FROM @T T1
           WHERE T0.ts > T1.ts
           AND T1.value >= 5
           AND T1.value <= 95
           ORDER BY t1.ts DESC
       ) As prev_value
FROM @T T0
ORDER BY ts DESC
```

Results:

```
ts                      value   prev_value
2019-09-22 00:00:00     90      75
2019-09-21 23:10:05     75      85
2019-09-21 23:09:00     85      70
2019-09-21 22:09:00     0       70
2019-09-21 14:09:00     70      NULL
```